# Listing teamdrive in google drive sdk with service account

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to list the team drives using service account (domain wide delegation is enabled), when i do so with just the "teamdrives().list()" i am getting a blank response.

```
{
  "kind" : "drive#teamDriveList",
  "teamDrives" : [ ]
}
```

If i use "teamdrives().list().setUseDomainAdminAccess(true).setQ("name='Test'")" or "teamdrives().list().setUseDomainAdminAccess(true)" i am getting below error.

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
  "domain" : "global",
  "location" : "q",
  "locationType" : "parameter",
  "message" : "Invalid Value",
  "reason" : "invalid"
} ],
  "message" : "Invalid Value"
}
```

Below is the code block,

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("client_secret.json");
new GoogleCredential();
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
        .fromStream(in)
        .createScoped(SCOPES);
Drive _service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
tdllist = _service.teamdrives().list().setUseDomainAdminAccess(true).setQ("name='Test'");
TeamDriveList _tdl = tdllist.execute();
```

Hoping someone will point what i am doing wrong or an efficient way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks and Regards
KKG

**Update**
After some research got to know that *"teamdrives().list()"* is listing the teamdrive that the user has access to, so i guess that part is working as it is suppose to. But the remaining is still a mystery.